# Character encoding in tomcat

Tags: tomcat, character-encoding

I have a problem with encoding in Tomcat 6.0. On all jsp pages I've specified

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

and `pageEncoding="UTF-8"` in page directive. But when I pass parametres(cyrillic letters) by get or post methods I have another symbols that I have entered. I've read that to fix this issue in post methods i have to set  `request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");` And it's really helps me. Also I've read that to fix it in get methods I have to specify URIEncoding="UTF-8" in Connector element in server.xml. And it also really works for get methods, but only if I don't specify `request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");`. So, if I specify both of them, only post method's parameter passing works well.
How can I do that also with get method?

**edit**
when i'm using form to pass the parameters through GET methods URIEncoding in server.xml works. But if I use response.senRedirect()(which is also using GET method) method in servlet it modifies cyrillic parametres with another symbols

**solved**
The problem was solved using java.net.URLEncoder. Every parameter has to be encoded by `URLEncoder.encode(par, "UTF-8")`. Then it will be displayed correctly.

Comment: Can you install Firefox/Firebug and paste some HTTP request/response headers here?

Comment: I think you're confusing what goes from and what comes to the server. Try the Accept-Encoding HTTP header.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue by adding `URIEncoder=UTF-8` in both http and ajp connector of tomcat server.xml. Did nothing other than this. I am using Spring, apache/tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

I also think that you should use **only** the JSP *page* directive and not the *meta* tag as well. I can't say if that causes the problem but it is unnecessary.

I found the following useful:

[UTF-8: The Secret of Character Encoding](http://htmlpurifier.org/docs/enduser-utf8.html)

[The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)